# Setup magento 2 error?

Tags: magento2, magento2-dev-beta

I m trying to setup magento 2 MAGETWO-40129: M2 GitHub Update. but get error when 
Installing... 70%
[image]

In  php.ini i'm trying to set values

xdebug.max_nesting_level=50000,

memory_limit=256M,

but it's not working.

Comment: Which branch code are you use from Github ?

Comment: i get it in here https://github.com/magento/magento2/releases

Answer (score 1):

You must be Download magento2 from here

```
https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/master
```

Follow magento installation steps.

Comment: i'm try it. but get same issue. @S H Patel

Comment: Kindly provide step which is you follow and send me error screen.

Comment: i'm follow magento install  guide. 
you see error in my question update.

Comment: I "try again" a few times

Comment: I can't see any error in your screen.

Comment: Message error: "Installation is incomplete.
Check the console log for errors before trying again."
in console log 
"Module 'Magento_Eav':

Module 'Magento_Customer':

Module 'Magento_BundleImportExport':

Module 'Magento_CacheInvalidate':

Module 'Magento_Indexer':

Module 'Magento_Cms':

Module 'Magento_CatalogImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Catalog':
Installing data.. "

Comment: Please upload your error screen shots. I can's see any error in console log.

Comment: sr i'm updated.

Comment: New downlable magento setup with new folder or not ?

Comment: yes. i dowloadable in https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/master.

Comment: i'm setup with begin new.

Comment: Yes but set up it with fresh directory or any existing directory ?

Comment: in localhost width fresh directory.

Comment: Kindly add full console log in your comment.

Comment: it does not show any errors

Comment: after many "try again".  it worked. setup Success . 
why you got this error. Do You know ?.
 issue related to  speed  import database or not. Thanks

Comment: I can't understand you above comment. can you explain agian ?

Comment: I have successfully setup. after many click button "try again". So, do you know why get error. It is related to speed database import it?

Comment: memory_limit should be at least 768M. Edit it in php.ini then restart your web server